# Closing Stock Value

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am working on Powerbi. I need to calculate the closing stock value.
Here i am attaching the image link.

https://www.mediafire.com/file/wnxq5hh91jrwp2y/cgs.JPG/file

As i use the below formula in Closing Stock Measure

```
Closing Stock = 
CALCULATE (
    [Movement],
    FILTER (
        ALLEXCEPT ( mak_stockInHandValue, mak_stockInHandValue[GName],mak_stockInHandValue[ItCode] ),
        mak_stockInHandValue[TransactDatee] <= MAX ( mak_stockInHandValue[TransactDatee] )
    )
)
```

It is showing me the correct result  on stock but when i am using the same formula in closing stock value measurement it is not giving me correct result.

if you can see in 2017 closing value should be  24673942+166903972-171299624 =20,278,290
I am also attaching the file in url of media fire

https://www.mediafire.com/file/wntdtu9pa04qnub/cgs_new.pbix/file

Please any one help in this

For Further Info

Closing stock Value =  Closing Stock Value previous + initemvalue - outitemvalue

This is general term to get the Closing Stock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because in your calculations you use `Avg Func` which varies depending on the selection you make. See image below:

[image]

In 2016 the value per item is `28,426.20`, but when you calculate `Movement Value` by applying a filter on the dates, the value per item is `27,094.46` which will affect the numbers that you used for previous period.

I've had a look in your model and you seem to have two columns with Price, I guess you need to use them to determine the out value, something like this:

```
OutItemvaluee = 
  IF(mak_stockInHandValue[OutQty] > 0, 
     mak_stockInHandValue[Price] + mak_stockInHandValue[pricen],
     0)
```

And then change your `outitemvalue` formula to be:

```
outitemvalue = SUM(mak_stockInHandValue[OutItemvaluee])
```

edit: I had a look at your model, please see updated answer.

Comment: When i am adding these its giving me 0 values in OutItemvaluee  new column and the second formula its giving error because you use 2 time ==

Comment: You need to find a way to determine the price correctly, please see updated answer, but I did notice there are cases where both price and pricen fields are 0, which might be a data issue.